# Ways to avoid storing additional arrays in memory when performing operations on large matrices?

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am working on a Matlab script which does calculations on 3D matrices (the actual code is iterating a field to solve a differential equation over time in 3D space). There a many functions, but I have included a simplified example below which illustrates the problem.

The code stores in memory the variables `A`, `K`, and `B`. It is unavoidable to store these, so that's fine. The function `calculate_E_values()` then calcultes some values based on these three matrices:

```matlab
A = complex( rand(64,64,64,'double') );
K = rand(64,64,64,'double');
B = rand(64,64,64,'double');

[E1, E, E32] = calculate_E_values(A, K, B);

function [E1, E2, E3] = calculate_E_values(A, K, B)

A_sq = abs(A).^2;
A_hat = fftn( ifftshift(A) );    
L_hat = -K.*A_hat;            
L = fftshift( ifftn(L_hat) );

% Calculate E1
E1I = -1/2 * real( conj(A).*L );
E1 = sum(sum(sum( E1I )));

% Calculate E2
E2I = B.*A_sq;
E2 = sum(sum(sum( E2I )));

% Calculate E3
E3I = -1/2 * real( conj(A).*L ) + ( B + A_sq ).*A_sq;
E3 = sum(sum(sum( E3I )));

end
```

Now, the problem comes when the function `calculate_E_values()` is entered. Due to the fact that I have assigned temporary variables, the workspace just before exiting this function and returning to the main script looks like the following:

[image]

It can be seen that many additional arrays have been created. In my real code, I am wanting to work with larger arrays (e.g 512 x 512 x 512), and these additional copies are then leading to "out-of-memory" errors.

My question is: Is there a better structure / style to follow which avoids this?

My thoughts:

1. I could combine multiple things on one line, but this would severely impact readability in the real, more complicated code. For example,

```matlab
E1 = sum(sum(sum( -1/2 * real( conj(A).*fftshift( ifftn(-K.*fftn( ifftshift(A) )) ) ) )));
```

(In addition, A_sq for example is used twice, so putting it on one line would increase execution time).

2. I could assign a temporary variable `TMP`, and keep overwriting it - but again, this would severely impact readability. I would also need to store `TMP` itself. For example,

```matlab
TMP = fftn( ifftshift(A) );    
TMP = -K.*TMP;            
TMP = fftshift( ifftn(TMP) );

TMP = -1/2 * real( conj(A).*TMP );
E1 = sum(sum(sum( TMP )));
```

3. I guess it would be nice if I could use the variable names as some kind of reference, without actually storing variables?

Are there any better approaches, or a nice way around this problem in Matlab?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no other way. You can if you want just `clearvars` and clear selected variables. But there is no way to go around this. What I tend to do is have the memory intensive code in a comment and say "this one liner does all that above". When you work with memory expensive things, then you need to start doing tricks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Okay thanks for your comment. I will take a similar approach. Out of interest, when you say "start doing tricks", do you have a good reference for the types of things you mean, so I can learn a little more? Also, is this problem specific to Matlab, or is there another language that I could write the code in, which has a feature for avoiding this problem?

Comment: Not really. What I mostly mean is that at that point you need to be aware, and really there is no much mistery, other than checking how much memory each function takes and optimizing that. If you work in a language that allows you to manage the memory (e.g. C/C++) then there are tons of tricks to learn, but otherwise, just "be aware" is the best I can tell you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People might have different opinions about how to implement this, but they would all agree to overwrite intermediate variables. I would do it this way:

```matlab
function [E1, E2, E3] = calculate_E_values(A, K, B)

A_sq = abs(A).^2;

L = fftn(ifftshift(A)); % = A_hat
L = -K.*L;              % = L_hat
L = fftshift(ifftn(L));

E1 = -1/2 * real( conj(A).*L );
E1 = sum(sum(sum( E1 )));

E2 = B.*A_sq;
E2 = sum(sum(sum( E2 )));

E3 = -1/2 * real( conj(A).*L ) + ( B + A_sq ).*A_sq;
E3 = sum(sum(sum( E3 )));

end
```

You might also do it like this, though it’s not as readable:

```matlab
L = fftshift(ifftn(... 
       -K.*...
       fftn(ifftshift(A))));
```

You could also `clear L_hat` when you no longer need it, but using `clear` within a function could slow it down significantly, it is not recommended.

Unrelated to your question: you should use `sum(E1(:))` rather than `sum(sum(sum(E3)))`.

Comment: `sum(E3, 'all')` is another option in recent versions of MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wrote as my Option 2, right? But you would allow E1, E2 and E3 to all been assigned to memory, in addition to your L?

Comment: @teeeeee I’m showing 3 solutions. My first solution looks like yours a bit, but I propose adding a comment to show what you’re calculating (since you said this was unclear). Also, `L` is needed in the computation of `E1` and `E3`, so you can’t overwrite it when computing `E1`, as you do in your example. Other than that, yes, I think the right way to do this is overwriting variables you don’t need any more.